# Better way to communicate between threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, ipc

So I have been trying to create an asynchronous web server using epoll. For logging facilities, I came up with create a thread which will log messages to a file. Write now, I am using pthread_mutex_t and pthread_cond_t to signal the thread to write to the file. Can I do better than this? What would be the most efficient way to communicate with the thread without adding a lot of overhead?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

char msg[1024];

pthread_cond_t cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int print_log = 0 ;

time_t now;

#define LOG_FILE(log_msg)   do { pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); \
                            print_log = 1; \
                            strcpy(msg,log_msg); \
                            pthread_cond_signal(&cv); \
                            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); } while(0) 

time_t now;

void* log_(void* param){

    FILE* fp = (FILE*)param;
    
    
    while(1){

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while(!print_log)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cv,&mutex);

        time(&now);
        char* cur_time = ctime(&now);
        cur_time[strlen(cur_time)-1] = '\0';

        fprintf(fp,"[%s] %s\n", cur_time, msg);
        
        fflush(fp);

        print_log = 0;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    }
}

int init_logger(const char* log_file){
    pthread_t thread;
    FILE* fp = fopen(log_file,"a");
    if( fp == NULL ){
        perror("fopen()");
        fprintf(stderr,"failed to open file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if( pthread_create(&thread,NULL,log_,(void*)fp) < 0 ){
        perror("pthread_create()");
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create the thread.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if( pthread_detach(thread) < 0 ){
        perror("pthread_detach()");
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create the thread.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Another idea that I had was to create a queue which my main thread will fill up, and the logger will only log messages when certain number of messages have accumulated in the queue, so as to reduce that amount of calling pthread_mutex_(un)lock() and pthread_cond_signal().
Would making the I/O asynchronous help too in this case as well? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do i understand it correctly, that you use two threads, one for `epoll` and the other for logging messages produced by the operations from the first thread? If that is the case, the overhead is the logging thread. What is the reason for that? File IO is buffered, if necessary increase the buffer size.

Comment: Is this the only process that will be writing to the log file?  Just use `fprintf()` directly from the thread that needs to log data.  [Each write to the log file will be atomic](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2p7): "Each stream has an associated lock that is used to prevent data races when multiple threads of execution access a stream, and to restrict the interleaving of stream operations performed by multiple threads."  That won't work if multiple processes are writing to the file.  In that case, though, you can use `open(...,O_APPEND...);`, format your string, then `write()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yup, only this process accesses the file.

Comment: If there's just one sinlge logging thread anyway you might want to profile how much time you are losing by logging directly from this single thread. Maybe you discover that it's just not worth all this mess with multi-threading…

Answer (score 4):

First, you have a bug.  If you invoke LOG_FILE multiples times in a row before the `log_` thread wakes up, the last call wins and discards all the other messages from getting written to disk.  We'll come back to that later.

The biggest thing you can do is have two queues for logging.  One for the active worker threads to write to.  And the other is for the log writer thread to dump the other queue to file.

Basically, it works like this:

- You have two string queues (linked list of strings)
- Each time you log an event, you're appending a string to the "active" queue that has its **own** mutex for multiple threads to write to. There's also a mutex for gating which queue is active
- After you log an event, you signal via condition variable to the log thread that there's data available
- When the log thread gets signaled, it uses another mutex or atomic primitive to "swap" which queue is active for the other threads to write to.
- The log thread takes the lock of the now non-active queue (the one that it previously swapped for) and dequeus all message in that queue to file. And here's the win. This thread is now writing to disk without blocking any other thread.
- The log thread can swap back the active queue again to the other queue to see if has messages that were queued before going back into a wait condition. Repeat until there is nothing left to write to disk.

Some pseduo code.

Here's a declaration and some primitives for an individual log queue:

```
struct MessageNode {
   const char* msg;
   const char* next;
};

struct MessageQueue {
    MessageNode*  head;     // this points to the front of the linked list
    MessageNode*  tail;     // this pointer to the back of the linked list
    pthread_mutex_t mut;    // for multple threads to write to THIS queue
};

void InitMessageQueue(MsesageQueue* mq) {
    pthread_mutex_init(&mq->mut, NULL);
    mq->head = NULL;
    mq->tail = NULL;
}

void LogToQueue(MessageQueue* mq, const char* msg) {

    MessageNode* node = allocateMessageNode();         // could be malloc(sizeof(MessageNode))
    node->msg = allocateMessageBuffer(strlen(msg)+1);  // can be malloc(N)
    node->next = NULL;
    strcpy(node->msg, msg);
    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mq->mut);
        if (mq->tail == NULL) {
           mq->head = node;
           mq->tail = node;
        } else {
            mq->tail->next = node;
        }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mq->mut);
}
```

Nothing too crazy with the above. It's just a thread safe linked list of strings. Notice that I have a pair of undefined functions allocating strings and nodes. You can use `malloc`, but you can optimize this by having your own heaps (memory pools) for these objects.

Now let's introduce the logging object itself, its constructor function, and the logging thread itself

```
struct LogStruct {
    MessageQueue mq1;
    MessageQueue mq2;
    MessageQueue* activeQueue;
    pthread_mutex_t activeQueueMutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    size_t msgIndex; // number of messages written - used as the condition itself
    bool exitFlag;   // if set, the the log thread will exit

    FILE* file;

    pthread_t thread;
}

void InitGlobalQueue(LogStruct* log) {
    // initialize each message queue
    InitMessageQueue(&log->mq1);
    InitMessageQueue(&log->mq2);

    // set the activeQueue to the first queue
    log->activeQueue = &log->mq1;

    // initielize the thread primitives
    pthread_mutex_init(&log->activeQueueMutex);
    pthread_cond_init(&log->cond);

    // every condition variable needs a condition to check
    // in our case, it's a simple counter
    log->msgIndex = 0;

    // Now put your code to open the log file here
    file = fopen(...);

    // now kick off the log thread
    log->exitFlag = false;
    pthread_create(&log->t1, NULL, LogWokerThread, log);
}

void LogWorkerThread(void* param) {
    LogStruct* log = (LogStruct*)param;
    size_t lastKnownIndex = (size_t)-1;
    MessageQueue* inactiveQueue;

    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&log->activeQueueMutex);

        if (log->exitFlag == true) {
            break;
        }

        while((lastKnownIndex == log->msgIndex) && (!log->exitFlag)) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&log->activeQueueMutex, &log->cond); // WAIT for a message to arrive into the active queue
        }

        lastKnownIndex = log->msgIndex;

        // swap the queues
        inactiveQueue = log->activeQueue;
        log->activeQueue = (&log->mq1 == log->activeQueue) ? &log->mq2 : &log->mq1;
        
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&log->activeQueueMutex); // unlock

        // Write everything to disk while not holding any locks
        MessageNode* node = inactveQueue->head;
        while (node) {
            fprintf("%s\n", node->msg);
            deallocateMessageBuffer(node->msg);   // can be free(node->msg);
            deallocateMessageNode(&node);         // can be free(node);
            node = node->next;
        }
    }
}
```

And now all we need is a global Logger object and a global function for writing to the logs:

```
void LogImpl(LogStruct* log, const char* message) {
     pthread_mutex_lock(&log->activeQueueMutex);
     LogToQueue(log->activeQueue, message);
     log->msgIndex++;
     pthread_cond_signal(&log->cond); // signal the log thread to wake up
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&log->activeQueueMutex);
}

LogStruct logger; // the global logger

void Log(const char* msg) {
    LogImpl(&logger, msg);
}
```

The `main` just needs to invoke `InitGlobalQueue(&logger)` on startup.  You will also need to write some functions for properly shutting down the thread. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

There's a couple of critical optimizations that can be made.

- MessageQueue itself does not need the `mut` member mutex. Given that each time LogImpl is called, it has to hold lock the activeQueueMutex lock, that's a sufficient gate for keeping the individual queues safe.  `LogToQueue` doesn't need to take its own lock.
- Replace`LogStruct.activeQueueMutex` with a **reader-writer** lock. Otherwise, the per-message queue lock is near useless since the outer `activeQueueLock` is acquired by both threads. The LogWorkerThread acquires the lock for writing. The other threads issuing log events just need to acquire the lock for reading.
- Possibly replace the double-queue with a single (or pair) of **atomic stacks**. Each thread would push to the top of the atomic stack.  When the logger wakes up, it reverses the entire stack before writing each node to a file. Lockless programming is incredibly difficult to get right, so tread carefully after googling for `atomic stack`
- Consider implementing `allocateMessageNode`, `allocateMessageBuffer`, `deallocateMessageNode` , and `deallocateMessageBuffer` using your own "pools" of preallocated fixed sized buffers so as not to the performance impacting `malloc` and `free` unless you need more buffers added to the pools.

If you implement these optimizations, you'll a very high performance logger that has minimal impact on multi-threaded performance.

Wow... that's a lot.  There's probably some bugs above. But I hope you get the general gist of ideas.

Comment: This looks wonderful. And yeah, I don't think I would be needing a mutex per messageQueue because I intend to have only one thread write to the message Queue while the logger thread reads from the message queue and write to the file. I think it'd be also better to log the message to file when I have some decent amount of messages in the queue, so as to reduce the amount of syscall that fwrite() would do. What do you think of that?

Comment: @Cardinal - sounds good. You'll need at least one mutex or atomic primitive for "swapping" queues.

Comment: Aren't we supposed to change msgIndex back to lastKnownIndex? Otherwise, the pthread_cond_wait() won't be executed next time?

Comment: @Cardinal - correct. I'll update the code above.

Comment: Two ring buffers of some reasonable size might even be more performant – for the price of that one possibly getting full (requiring re-allocation of the buffer or discarding messages). But in that case we might need to ask ourselves if the writer thread is not over-stressed anyway, which we wouldn't detect with linked lists that easily (unless providing a counter). Actually same advantages as the stack without need for reversal.

Comment: Two separate mutexes don't appear meaningful to me: We need to prevent the writer from accessing the queue just having been swapped while some logging thread is still appending. Thus the writer will have to wait for the loggers anyway and thus hold the queue mutex as well. So independent of the number of threads (@Cardinal) we would get along well with just the activeQueueMutex, being held for appending as well.